# For loop python?

Tags: java, python, loops, for-loop

I am new to Python. As a part of my algorithm, I am required to swap the element in an array. I tried to convert my Java implementation to Python and ended up getting an exception (list out of range exception).

In Java - I'm using the for loop like this:

```java
for (i = left; i <= right; i++) {
    swap(a, left, i); //a is an array, left and right (int)
    permute(a, left+1, right);
    swap(a, left, i); //backtrack
}
```

```py
# python implementation
i = left
while(i<=right):
    i = i+1
    swap(listArr,left,i)

    permute(listArr,(left+1),right)

    swap(listArr,left,i)
```

Please help me to replicate the Java for loop in Python. `permute` is a recursive function and takes:

```
permute (char [] a, int left, int right)
```

Comment: python programs typically use a for loop for this: `for i in range(left, right):`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Getting to know a new language is definitely a common source of confusion, and a perfectly reasonable and appropriate subject for a question on SO.

Comment: @Seth so? It doesn't exempt the requirement for a [mcve], and the OP's request for tutoring is still not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment `i` at the *end* of your loop:

```
i = left
while(i<=right):
    swap(listArr,left,i)

    permute(listArr,(left+1),right)

    swap(listArr,left,i)
    i = i + 1
```

As a note, to increment `i`, you could use `i += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(left,right+1):
    swap(a, left, i); //a is an array, left and right (int)
    permute(a, left+1, right);
    swap(a, left, i); //backtrack
```